# What's our site's elevator pitch?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

According to the [Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223674/the-real-essential-questions-of-every-beta), one question that the community should discuss is:

**What is the elevator pitch for our site?**

> Imagine you’ve just gotten on an elevator with a friendly stranger. You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them. What would you say? The elevator pitch is a brief sentence that describes what your site is about.
>
> This helps in visualising what your community is about and what it is going to be. If you have trouble describing your community in one-line, then its a sign that the community needs to take a relook at its scope and purpose.

Please post each submission as one answer so it can be individually voted upon.

Answer (score 7):

> Language Learning is a community of passionate polyglots, language learners, and language teachers looking for information about various language acquisition techniques, the objective effectiveness of language learning methods, and the use of software in the language acquisition process.

Comment: What do you think about this version: "Language Learning is a community of passionate polyglots, language learners, and language teachers looking for information about various language acquisition *and teaching techniques*, the objective effectiveness of *these* methods, and the use of software *to that end*." ? (proposals in cursive) Since I'm not a native speaker of English I'm not really sure if the last proposal ("to that end") is proper usage in this context...

Comment: That's one slooooow elevator.

Comment: @brandaemon Or just a really, really tall building

Comment: @PythonMaster "You have precisely one floor to describe your community to them."

Comment: @brandaemon Make that a 600+ feet tall floor

Comment: @PythonMaster the architect is so fired.

Answer (score 5):

> Language Learning Stack Exchange is a helpful community where language teachers and learners can find answers to their questions.

Answer (score 2):

The current pitch, being used in the tour:

> Language Learning Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for students, teachers, polyglots, and anyone interested in the techniques of second-language acquisition.

Comment: I would suggest that at minimum we update this to say "language acquisition" rather than specifically second-language acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

> Language Learning is a Stack Exchange community for people seeking
>   information on Language learning process.

Answer (score 0):

> Ever wanted to ask questions about learning new languages and have
>   them be answered by experts around the world?  Take my card.*

<sub>* has the site URL</sub>

Comment: Do you have cards with the site URL on it?

Comment: @wythagoras We should make some!

Answer (score 0):

I think the teaching aspect has been ignored too much so far (not just in the context of this question but also elsewhere on this site), so here is my version:

> Language Learning Stack Exchange is a Q&A site for people who are passionate about learning or teaching languages. Anyone can ask or answer questions about methods, strategies, techniques, software, etc. for learning or teaching languages in general or just specific aspects of language. Both questions and answers should be fact-based, not a matter of opinion. Good quality questions and answers can be upvoted by other users and thereby become more prominent.